# WiFi Error: "Failed to connect to network"

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, troubleshooting

Intermittently, when I try to connect to a WiFi network, I get the following error message as a toast message:

> Failed to connect to network

The message pops up immediately upon attempting to connect, so clearly it isn't trying and failing. I haven't found any mention of an error in the logs. The affected networks are ones that I've previously connected to with no change in settings.

**How can I figure out what the problem is?**

I've got a rooted Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.1.1 and the stock ROM. This question is related to [another question that I posted earlier](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29291/14562), but this one is more about how to find the source of a particular error message, so its focus is different.

## Additional Details

Here are some more details based on the comments:

- I've observed this on my home and work networks. One is identified as WPA2 PSK and the other is identified as WPA/WPA2 PSK.
- I haven't powered off the phone as described in the [troubleshooting guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/troubleshoot-wi-fi-connections-on-your-android-phone/2357) mentioned in the comments. However, I have rebooted to no avail (using the reboot command that's available on rooted phones).
- Forgetting the network and re-adding it has no effect. In fact, if I forget the network I can no longer successfully re-add it.
- The wireless password hasn't changed.
- There's no proxy configured when I'm on wireless. However, I run Onavo Extend when I'm on a data connection. Disabling it has no effect.
- I've switched from DHCP to static IP addresses. Doing so reduced the frequency of problems and seems to have eliminated my earlier issue where wifi would be randomly dropped.
- Wifi sleep is set to "Only when plugged in." I don't think it's relevant because my issue is establishing a connection in the first place (such as when I arrive at home or at work), not maintaining one.

Note that despite all these troubleshooting steps,**my initial goal is to find an actual error message or log entry that gives useful information about the problem.**

Comment: What kind of wireless network? WPA? WPA2? WEP? Go through this guide just in case: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/troubleshoot-wi-fi-connections-on-your-android-phone/2357

Comment: @Enigma: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question.

Comment: Try disabling sleep entirely and downloading a third-party wifi connection tool from the app store. There is likely one that provides a nice output log as well. What other application services do you have running besides the stock ones?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? If so, how? Don't hesitate to answer your own question, Scott -- you know that's perfectly fine here :)

Comment: @Izzy: My issue persists. I haven't found any solution.

Comment: Sorry to read that. Few hints: I read Android sometimes has trouble with WiFi using auto WPA/WPA2. People solved that part by fixing it to one of the two (try first one, then the other; also try WEP, just for the records so you see if encryption is part of the problem). Also check channels, maybe it works better on a different channel (stick to the first 11, but try finding one that's not so "overcrowded").

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue you are having on my LG 4X HD. I updated to 4.1 and now I have loads of problems with wifi. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Patrick: My problem is as yet unresolved.

Comment: As it was not mentioned here explicitly: Has one of you two tried to capture a `logcat` when the problem appeared? That might turn something up. Up to ICS (4.0) you can use one of the logcat apps from Google Play; however, as with JB they no longer can access anything but their own log entries, you might need to use `adb logcat` then (or root your device).

Comment: I tried but got nothing relevant. By the way, for rooted phones it's possible to convert alogcat to a system app. Then it works as advertised under Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have custom recovery installed? I have had this problem twice on a Galaxy S2, and what fixed it for me every time was running a permissions fix from recovery mode.

If that doesn't work, try deleting your WiFi config file. Not sure what it is on the Nexus, but I'm guessing it'll be something along the lines of `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` or `/data/misc/wifi/wpa.conf`. Obviously you should make backups before deleting anything. Note that you'll lose all your WiFi settings if you do this.

Comment: The guy with the nexus isn't the one who posted the bounty, I bumped for attention. I've got an LG Optimus 4X HD. Not wildly different and I don't think its platform specific. Currently don't have recovery installed, although have been investigating that as part of a solution to this issue (move to CyanoGen 10.1). I can't see /data/misc/* at all, although I realise my fw update has dropped root access. Would that block access? I've go ta whole weekend set aside to get something going. I'll update when I know more. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick - I would be surprised if you can see anything in `/data` at all without root access. On every phone I've tested, an app can only see its own user data in `/data/data/app.name` and nothing else. If you do get root access, also check for a directory named `/data/wifi`. Some phones use that instead of `/data/misc/wifi`.

Comment: Sure. thanks for confirming, looks like I'm stuck in front of a computer all weekend then. Lets hope the sun goes away eh?

Comment: Haha yeah, enjoy the weekend. Let me know if your problem gets resolved.

Comment: Unable to get root. Seems I have issues getting to my phone via ADB. I'm still very much a noob at this stuff :( although I did find an app that helped...

Comment: Note that ADB does not give full root access, only partial root access, unless you have a kernel patched with insecure ADB.

Comment: The unlock process for the p880 on 4.1.2 requires either ADB Shell and running some stuff, or ADB Sideload *.zip, neither of which work (various connection errors during the process).

Comment: I wished I saw this months earlier! Soooo many thanks! So many thanks!!!

Comment: `running a permissions fix` what? on what file(s)? I don't understand what you're trying to say in the first paragraph at all

Comment: on my system the file from your second paragraph was located at `/data/vendor/wifi/something` and deleting it and rebooting also didn't help, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I think this part of your question is key:

> I've switched from DHCP to static IP addresses. Doing so reduced the frequency of problems and seems to have eliminated my earlier issue where wifi would be randomly dropped.

IP addressing issues could certainly cause you troubles like this. Static addressing is only treating the symptoms, though, not curing the disease. Assuming the APs you're connecting to haven't had their DHCP settings changed, focus on investigating how your phone is acting as a DHCP client. I found a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40437) in which several users report the same trouble you're having (the author actually references [one of your previous questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/29291/11343)). One of the commenters [found log entries](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40437#c27) related to DHCP; you mentioned in a comment that you didn't find any relevant log entries but did you see any that look like this commenter's?

> Apr  1 05:26:12 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[522]: DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.200.225 a0:0b:ba:83:65:32
>
> Apr  1 05:26:12 unknown daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[522]: DHCPNAK(br0) 192.168.200.225 a0:0b:ba:83:65:32 wrong address

Additionally, [a later commenter](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40437#c37) found that the DHCP client service `dhcpcd` was not running on his device. He explains:

> I started researching a bit, using good old Linux console and "ps"
>   command. I noticed that:
>
> - every time I could not connect, dhcpcd was not running.
> - at least several times, Kingsoft Office process was running when the problem appeared.
>
> So, what I did was:
>
> - uninstalled Kingsoft Office,
> - switch to static IP on all networks I use often (home, work, friends, family). I also disabled WiFi power management (read
>     somewhere that it could help).
>
> After these, problem disappeared. It's
>   been gone for 2 weeks now!

He found that the DHCP client service's absence was correlated with one of his apps. Reconfigure your device to use DHCP, try to connect to one of the problem APs, then use [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) (or similar) to run the same investigation he did by typing the command `ps | grep dhcp`. The output should look something like the following:

`dhcp      4858  1     924    552   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/bin/dhcpcd`

This means that the `dhcpcd` process is running. If `dhcpcd` is not running, you'll simply be returned nothing. If that's the case, type `ps` again to get a list of all current processes. Do you notice any correlations between an app you've installed and the problems you're having? As a temporary work-around, trying starting the service again by typing `sudo dhcpcd`, then try again to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work round, if not resolve, the issue at hand.

In short I installed [Wifi Ruler - Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hogdex.WifiRuler&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5ob2dkZXguV2lmaVJ1bGVyIl0.), which overrides the stock wifi connection manager.

This allows me to click and connect to any AP that I come across with no issue.

It does loads of other stuff, finally I can prevent my phone from connecting to my neighbours incredibly strong open wifi.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have set mobile data limit. I know it's weird on my samsung Google nexus maguro I removed the limit and wifi returned back to normal.

However I had the same issue on Nexus 7 grouper, I tried various apps and tricks on the net. But finally I had to reflash the Cyanogenmod to get wifi working on it.

Answer (score -1):

I gave this answer to a disconnection query earlier but there is some resonance here.

> I think I can guess what is happening. When I first started using free hotspots I was connecting with no problem and often they will have a logon screen to insert the locale password. Some places however like hotels seem to give free access for a limited time or for first use without logging in and then later they will expect you to register.
>
> When I have returned to these places a second time I find that the phone finds the network and claims to be connected but every use returns a network error or appears to connect and get cut off. In fact I am getting rerouted to their logon page, only it seems to often only open in background in gingerbread so you don't know it is happening.
>
> After fiddling around you can sometimes get the logon page to show and then register. Often I can only do this by attempting a google search. Google somehow seems to know to route via the logon pages whereas other apps play ignorant."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as I stated in my question, I'm experiencing these issues at home and work. Your issue with free Wi-Fi hotspots is, I presume, completely unrelated since you're experiencing issues getting outside despite having a connection to the hotspot.

Answer (score -2):

Try to reboot your phone, you will find it again after rebooting.

Comment: Yes, "try rebooting" is a tried and true troubleshooting technique for all kinds of computer issues, but isn't really a long-term strategy nor does it identify the actual issue.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. I found it had to to with my Easy Battery Saver app. Messed around with the settings and it immediately connected.

Comment: "messed around with the settings" is hardly considered a helpful answer.