# WiFi Error: “Failed to connect to network” - Google Pixel 3xl, Android 11

Tags: wi-fi, google-pixel-3-xl

My Google Pixel 3XL was working perfectly fine and now it refuses to connect to wifi. It just says "Failed to connect to network" whenever and however I try.

I'm not running a custom ROM.
I have not installed anything new since it was working - it was working fine and then it wasn't
I haven't physically damaged my phone, wifi seems to be the only thing effected, all other functions are normal as far as I can see

Here is everything I've tried:

I've checked that the wifi router works by testing it with other devices.
I've tried connecting to new SSIDs that the phone has never met before
I've tried conneting in safe mode
I've installed the latest updates to my phone and tried again

This old question suggests that I delete a wifi config file: [WiFi Error: "Failed to connect to network"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/wifi-error-failed-to-connect-to-network) I cant access that file, probably because I'm not root. So that is probably not going to happen.

The next thing to try is a factory reset. But I really really want to avoid that.

Do any of you have anything else I can try?

Comment: Put it on airplane mode, wait for a little while and then try to connect // go to settings, delete saved networks. Sometimes this helps

Comment: Have you done a Network Settings Reset? Go to Settings, System, Reset Options, and select "Reset Wi-Fi, mobile & Bluetooth" and do that. Then reboot and test again. This does NOT effect any of your data like contacts, pictures, or apps.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks, but it didn't work. I even tried again in safe mode

Comment: @beeshyams thanks. But it didn't work

Comment: Sheena, looks like a hardware issue (considering it didn't work in safe mode). If you take it to service center, they will ask you to do a factory reset. Might as well try flashing the full stock image before going the repair route

Comment: I reset to factory settings and it worked. That's what I wanted to avoid but it is what it is. At least the phone still works

Comment: The Problem for me was that I set up my Wi-Fi with WPA3 + WPA2 which caused this failure and series of disconnects on other phones