# Samsung Galaxy S3 Wi-Fi problems

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3, connection-issues

My Samsung Galaxy S3 has major Wi-Fi problems.  It will connect to Wi-Fi for a few seconds, then it quits and won't connect to anything.  It happens at home, work, or anywhere else with Wi-Fi.  It's not the router. My laptop and other phone works fine with it.

If I turn off the Wi-Fi and then turn it back on again, it will work for a little while, but then, nothing, no connection to anything. I've researched the problem for days and seems like a lot of people are dealing with the same thing.

There are some supposed 'quick fixes' but none work for me. (dialing *#0011# on the phone to turn off power save mode, downloading a Wi-Fi Fixer app, doing a factory reset, trying to set a static IP - phone won't let me, and everything else, NOTHING WORKS!).

Is this a problem with the phone or the software?  Do I need to exchange the phone for a different one?

I even called Samsung and they claimed that no one else has ever reported a problem with this, even though there are hundred and hundreds of posts online about the issue.

Is Samsung doing anything about this or should I just give up and get a different phone all together?  By the way, it always says that I am connected to Wi-Fi. It just doesn't actually work.

I've read about having to set the router to G or N but I have no idea what the means or how to do it?  And besides, why should I have to do that?  Shouldn't the phone's wi-fi just work?  And how would I do this G or N setting at work?  Not gonna happen, so I'd be outta luck there.

So frustrating!!

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the hardware... nothing to do with the software

Comment: Strongly recommend looking at: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29291/wifi-connection-dropping

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Sprint version of the S3, see if Sprint Connections Optimizer is turned on under Settings > More Settings > Mobile Networks. Make sure it's turned off, as it can cause Wi-Fi to be a little funky sometimes.

Comment: The sprint connection optimizer is probably the worst most useless app of its kind.  It is truly horrific.